# How to create validation for zip code by country using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I have country dropdown list and zip code text box. i want to make validation for zip code by selection of country name using ASP.NET(C#).

Comment: Are you wanting to have a service that supplies a list of possible postcodes (or patterns) per country? or do you already have this, and you just want regular expression to validate what the end user inputs?  You can see a list of patterns here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 3rd party software is an option then you should look at companies like [melissadata](http://www.melissadata.com), [ups](http://ups.com) or [fedex](http://fedex.com). They all provide api's for address validation across the globe and zipcode and 3zip validation.